# Upgrading NVIDIA L4T (Linux 4 Tegra) GPU modules from 3.10 to Something Newer (Like 4.19 LTS)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, compiling, kernel-modules, gpu

I'm an owner of an ARM (armv7h) ChromeBook, in particular, it is the Acer ChromeBook 13 with an NVIDIA Tegra K1 GPU.  I've recently have been successfully able to run Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish) LTS using the Chrome OS (Linux 3.10) kernel, older Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) Xorg packages (as newer Xorg versions do not work with NVIDIA's blobs), paired with the proprietary NVIDIA L4T (Linux 4 Tegra) 21.8 to get working GPU acceleration.  So far, the system has been running smoothly for the most part, and the GPU still holds on despite its age.  The main issue is that this unit similar to Jetson TK1 users is relying on Linux 3.10 with NVIDIA's GPU kernel modules.

I prefer to use a more secure kernel.  This unit does actually support up to the latest Linux 6.x kernel (with only a few patches for added functionality) but it seems like no one has attempted to ever port L4T kernel modules to newer Linux kernel versions.  I prefer not to rely on such an old kernel, and I'm using the NVIDIA proprietary drivers as Nouveau is beyond just extremely broken for this GPU (there are many unresolved Mesa regressions that make this GPU unusuable with Nouveau unfortunately).  Nouveau is not an option in this case.  This won't be the first time I've ventured into kernel modification but this is a bit different.  At least the L4T kernel modules are open source.

I hope to at least bring the kernel up to 4.19 LTS (for now) with the Tegra GPU modules, but preferably an LTS release that won't be EOL that quickly (like 4.19 LTS).

What would you all recommend me doing in trying to bring up these kernel modules?  Where should I start?  Any help would be very greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

[L4T 21.8 Page](https://developer.nvidia.com/linux-tegra-r218)